# ctrl + r in linux / ubuntu terminal command line

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal

With <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> you can search in previous commands (in the terminal of Ubuntu). However, it always seems to display the last occurrence of the search term. Is there any way to browse through *all* results?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

After you type the few characters to search, you can press CTRL+R again to browse through the history that matches what you typed.

It will be limited to the history size though.

Comment: AWESOME! that's exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: For controlling history size, one can note that `HISTFILESIZE` controls the size of the history file (`~/.bash_history`), but `HISTSIZE` controls the size of the specific terminal history, and it is the latter that decides how far back `Ctrl+R` can look. I noted this on a machine where I had enlarged the former variable, but not the latter. Both are originally set to `500`, but if one wants more reverse searchable history saved, both variables need to be updated.

Answer (score 11):

You just need to press `CTRL-R` again.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to see all matching history lines at once, try `fc -ln | grep`.

```
mress:10077 Z$ fc -ln -100 | grep \^cd 
cd /Volumes/Development/android-sdk-mac_x86
cd ~/Downloads/MagicTrackpad.pkg
cd Resources
cd English.lproj
cd ../..
cd MagicTrackpadMultiTouchUpdate1.0.pkg
cd ..
cd
```

(`-100` means "the last 100 commands"; the default is 20, or you can specify a range.)

Answer (score 2):

For step on the search you have to `CTRL+R` again.

But if you want a list of the command you could use

```
history | grep 'command to search'
```